# How x86-64 Intel CPU understands how many bytes load into a register

Tags: memory, cpu, assembly, cache, intel

I have the following byte code one the left and and its byte representation on the right:

```
mov    eax, 0x1    ; 0:  b8 01 00 00 00          
mov    ebx, 0x2    ; 5:  bb 02 00 00 00          
add    eax, ecx    ; a:  01 c8
```

I am not sure that I understand correctly how CPU loads this byte code from cache to registers.

Here is my vision of the process. Let's assume that this byte code already in L1 cache.

As far as I understand:

1. CPU reads **single** byte `b8` and understands that this opcode means for him that he needs to load to the `EAX` register very next 32 bits [quick question: does CPU load this byte to the register or not?]
2. Therefore, CPU loads from cache to `EAX` next 4 bytes `01 00 00 00`
3. CPU reads **single** byte `bb` and understands that this opcode means for him that he needs to load to the `EAX` register next 32 bits
4. Therefore, CPU loads from cache to `EBX` very next 4 bytes `02 00 00 00`
5. CPU reads **single** byte `01` and understands that he needs to read one more byte to figure out what registers should be sumed.
6. So he reads the very next byte `c8` and understands that he needs to sum values in `EAX` and `EBX` registers

If my idea is correct it means that CPU reads from cache  not only 32 bit word per read, but although 1 byte per read. Am I correct?

If not, please provide me explanation how CPU executes this hex code.

Comment: We can't know how each CPU reads from cache and what kind of decoding queue they have. It might be different how CPUs from different manufactures work and how they do it. What you can only know is what each opcode does according to the programming model, i.e. a given sequence of opcodes does the thing it says it does. Internally a single CISC opcode can be translated into series of RISC opcodes, and even reordered for processing multiple threads of execution simultaneously.

Comment: The x86 specification specifies what the opcodes are, not how a specific CPU chooses to parse them, so you'd need to specify which CPU you're using and then hope it's documented somewhere in a manual.

Answer (score 1):

Most real world CPUs today fetch multiple bytes from the instruction cache at the same time (many cases, up to a full cache line, which is 64 bytes long). Multiple parallel decode engines then figure out the instruction boundaries of 1 or more instructions in that single cache read and proceed to issue several instructions in the downstream stages of scheduling and execution.

In other words, cache reads, decode, issue, scheduling and execution happens for multiple instructions at any given time for most superscalar processors (which most of mainstream processors are).